# What are the advantages of developing a frontend app inside a docker container?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, docker, web-applications

When developing for example an `angular 2`web app, why should I run it inside a docker container? I can see the following advantages:

- keeps host system clean
- same settings and versions on every machine

Regarding the fact that in a development environment `webpack` or an equivalent is used as a server, but not on production where only static build files are served, there are not many other similarities.

Are there any other real advantages?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding docker containers on a production environment, there are too many advantages, but surely it's up to you to see the advantages when you compare to your current architecture.

Some common are

- easy and fast deployment and updates
- easy recovery from failure (restart/recreate container)
- scalability (run as many as you need instances of an app in the same or different hosts)
- the containerization itself provides security: if someone hacks in, he'll be locked in the cointainer's scope and can't harm the host sytem
- easy service migration from one host to another

can't say enough though.

I'm editing because I understand your real question was about using docker in development state.
For me, some are:

- Standarization (exact same environment for every developer, regardless the OS used)
- Easy devel environment set up for new ppl or new OS installed
- Standarization brings build process automation easier
- Tests much alike real operation environment

Answer (score 1):

The main advantages are

- Platform Independent:
   It is independent of the OS you are developing your code.You can specify              which OS to run for your application.
- Handy to use:
   You can create the images with different configurations and run on different ports to test different use cases.
- Easy building process
- Easy resolution of any issues

Comment: If you have developing parallel projects then it should not be a blocker for you to checkout(git checkout) to that particular branch and test it out.Docker gives you the flexibility to create an image of each of your branch and run it on any port you want.So in this way you can be multiprocessor developer.:)